# Using ReactDOM.render in class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

I have a very unique issue where I need to render components with different ids on a site, and cannot render all the content under one ID.

I have been able to collect a JSON array through a GET request and have been able to get a for each loop for each array, however I just need to render that particular data with an ID passed from the array.

I have tried to use ReactDom.render in a class but I cannot find how this can be done & and I have current set `document.getElementById('modules')` to one particular div to begin with to see if that would render, but having no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Index.js
`

```
import { ColorModeScript } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import React, { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Theme from "./theme";
import Page from "./structure/Page";
import axios from "axios";


class Index extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          modules: [],
      };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
      if (currentPath === '/') {
          currentPath = '/home';
        }
      axios
          .get("/lite/modules" + currentPath)
          .then((response) => {
              const data = response.data;
              this.setState({ modules: data });
              
                Object.entries(data).forEach(data1 => {

                    var ModuleData = data1[1];
                    this.renderModule(ModuleData);
                });
                
          })
          .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
          });
  }

  renderModule(ModuleData){
    console.log(ModuleData);
    var divID = "module" + ModuleData.type;
    ReactDOM.render(
      <h1>demo</h1>,
      document.getElementById('modules')
    );
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <ChakraProvider theme={Theme}>
              <Page modules={this.state.modules} />
          </ChakraProvider>
      );
  }

 


}

export default Index;


// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers: https://cra.link/PWA
serviceWorker.unregister();

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: 
reportWebVitals();
```

`

Render multiple react components with different IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this to your constructor:

`this.renderModule = this.renderModule.bind(this)`

if you have another server for the DB:
you need to do that when using axios:

```
 axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL || '**LOCAL_SERVER_URL**'}/...`)
```